# Best way to display decimal without trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

Is there a display formatter that will output decimals as these string representations in c# without doing any rounding?

```
// decimal -> string

20 -> 20
20.00 -> 20
20.5 -> 20.5
20.5000 -> 20.5
20.125 -> 20.125
20.12500 -> 20.125
0.000 -> 0
```

{0.#} will round, and using some Trim type function will not work with a bound numeric column in a grid.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Do you have a maximum number of decimal places you'll ever need to display?  (Your examples have a max of 5).

If so, I would think that formatting with "0.#####" would do what you want.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dList = new decimal[] { 20, 20.00m, 20.5m, 20.5000m, 20.125m, 20.12500m, 0.000m };

        foreach (var d in dList)
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.#####"));
    }
```

Comment: And you can always throw an exorbitant* number of # symbols at the format.  *not scientific

Comment: +1 - incidentally, you don't need the leading #. "0.#####" works identically. And either way, this does round away from zero (just FYI).

Comment: @TrueWill Actually it does make a difference.  d==0.1m then "0.#" renders "0.1" and "#.#" renders ".1" without the leading 0.  Neither is wrong or right, just depends on what you want.

Answer (score 47):

I just learned how to properly use the `G` format specifier. See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#GFormatString). There is a note a little way down that states that trailing zeros will be preserved for decimal types when no precision is specified. Why they would do this I do not know, but specifying the maximum number of digits for our precision should fix that problem. So for formatting decimals, `G29` is the best bet.

```
decimal test = 20.5000m;
test.ToString("G"); // outputs 20.5000 like the documentation says it should
test.ToString("G29"); // outputs 20.5 which is exactly what we want
```

Comment: This will lead to 0.00001 displayed as 1E-05 though

Answer (score 20):

This string format should make your day: "0.#############################". Keep in mind that decimals can have at most 29 significant digits though.

Examples:

```
? (1000000.00000000000050000000000m).ToString("0.#############################")
-> 1000000.0000000000005

? (1000000.00000000000050000000001m).ToString("0.#############################")
-> 1000000.0000000000005

? (1000000.0000000000005000000001m).ToString("0.#############################")
-> 1000000.0000000000005000000001

? (9223372036854775807.0000000001m).ToString("0.#############################")
-> 9223372036854775807

? (9223372036854775807.000000001m).ToString("0.#############################")
-> 9223372036854775807.000000001
```

Comment: This is the most general answer to the problem. Not sure why this isn't the default "G" format for decimal. The trailing zeros add no information. Microsoft documentation has a weird caveat for decimal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString

However, if the number is a Decimal and the precision specifier is omitted, fixed-point notation is always used and trailing zeros are preserved.

Answer (score 11):

This is yet another variation of what I saw above. In my case I need to preserve all significant digits to the right of the decimal point, meaning drop all zeros after the most significant digit. Just thought it would be nice to share. I cannot vouch for the efficiency of this though, but when try to achieve aesthetics, you are already pretty much damned to inefficiencies.

```
public static string ToTrimmedString(this decimal target)
{
    string strValue = target.ToString(); //Get the stock string

    //If there is a decimal point present
    if (strValue.Contains("."))
    {
        //Remove all trailing zeros
        strValue = strValue.TrimEnd('0');

        //If all we are left with is a decimal point
        if (strValue.EndsWith(".")) //then remove it
            strValue = strValue.TrimEnd('.');
    }

    return strValue;
}
```

That's all, just wanted to throw in my two cents.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, based on [dyslexicanaboko's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c-sharp/12962160#12962160) answer, but independent of the current culture:

```
public static string ToTrimmedString(this decimal num)
{
    string str = num.ToString();
    string decimalSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    if (str.Contains(decimalSeparator))
    {
        str = str.TrimEnd('0');
        if(str.EndsWith(decimalSeparator))
        {
            str = str.RemoveFromEnd(1);
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string str, int characterCount)
{
    return str.Remove(str.Length - characterCount, characterCount);
}
```

Comment: Great. Except for SqlDecimal it is CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator despite regional settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `G0` format string if you are happy to accept scientific notation as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/dwhawy9k(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-general-g-format-specifier):

> Fixed-point notation is used if the exponent that would result from expressing the number in scientific notation is greater than -5 and less than the precision specifier; otherwise, scientific notation is used.

You can use this format string as a parameter to the `.ToString()` method, or by specifying it as a [within an interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string). Both are shown below.

```cs
decimal hasTrailingZeros = 20.12500m;
Console.WriteLine(hasTrailingZeros.ToString("G0")); // outputs 20.125
Console.WriteLine($"{hasTrailingZeros:G0}"); // outputs 20.125

decimal fourDecimalPlaces = 0.0001m;
Console.WriteLine(fourDecimalPlaces.ToString("G0")); // outputs 0.0001
Console.WriteLine($"{fourDecimalPlaces:G0}"); // outputs 0.0001

decimal fiveDecimalPlaces = 0.00001m;
Console.WriteLine(fiveDecimalPlaces.ToString("G0")); // outputs 1E-05
Console.WriteLine($"{fiveDecimalPlaces:G0}"); // outputs 1E-05
```

Answer (score 2):

Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string TrimDouble(this string temp)
    {
        var value = temp.IndexOf('.') == -1 ? temp : temp.TrimEnd('.', '0');
        return value == string.Empty ? "0" : value;
    }
}
```

Example code:

```
double[] dvalues = {20, 20.00, 20.5, 20.5000, 20.125, 20.125000, 0.000};
foreach (var value in dvalues)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --> {1}", value, value.ToString().TrimDouble()));

Console.WriteLine("==================");

string[] svalues = {"20", "20.00", "20.5", "20.5000", "20.125", "20.125000", "0.000"};
foreach (var value in svalues)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --> {1}", value, value.TrimDouble()));
```

Output:

```
20 --> 20
20 --> 20
20,5 --> 20,5
20,5 --> 20,5
20,125 --> 20,125
20,125 --> 20,125
0 --> 0
==================
20 --> 20
20.00 --> 2
20.5 --> 20.5
20.5000 --> 20.5
20.125 --> 20.125
20.125000 --> 20.125
0.000 --> 0
```

Comment: "20.00 --> 2" I think it is not good behaviour. To fix it call TrimEnd two times: TrimEnd('0'); TrimEnd(',');

Comment: DO NOT USE the code written above. @VadymK is correct that its behavior is flawed. It will trim trailing zeros that are BEFORE the period if there is no period.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible out-of-the-box but a simple method like this should do it

```
public static string TrimDecimal(decimal value)
{
    string result = value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (result.IndexOf('.') == -1)
        return result;

    return result.TrimEnd('0', '.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to do out of the box:

```
Decimal YourValue; //just as example   
String YourString = YourValue.ToString().TrimEnd('0','.');
```

that will remove all trailing zeros from your Decimal.

The only thing that you need to do is add `.ToString().TrimEnd('0','.');` to a decimal variable to convert a `Decimal` into a `String` without trailing zeros, like in the example above.

In some regions it should be a `.ToString().TrimEnd('0',',');` (where they use a comma instead of a point, but you can also add a dot and a comma as parameters to be sure).

(you can also add both as parameters)

Comment: gr8. Now you only have "0.0" left. Would procuce an empty string with your code.

Comment: Then I would suggest calling .ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.'). Also instead of '.' its better to have CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator so that it works across cultures.

Comment: @Mervin, please change your answer to reflect ΕГИІИО's comment. Your code would format `50.0m` as `5`, which is obviously an error.

Comment: Downvoting. This will turn 20 into 2 :/

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal val = 0.000000000100m;
string result = val == 0 ? "0" : val.ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethod {
  public static decimal simplify_decimal(this decimal value) => decimal.Parse($"{this:0.############}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following code:

```
    public static string DropTrailingZeros(string test)
    {
        if (test.Contains(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
        {
            test = test.TrimEnd('0');
        }

        if (test.EndsWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
        {
            test = test.Substring(0,
                test.Length - CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.Length);
        }

        return test;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have end up with this variant:

```
public static string Decimal2StringCompact(decimal value, int maxDigits)
    {
        if (maxDigits < 0) maxDigits = 0;
        else if (maxDigits > 28) maxDigits = 28;
        return Math.Round(value, maxDigits, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString("0.############################", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Advantages:

you can specify the max number of significant digits after the point to display at runtime;

you can explicitly specify a round method;

you can explicitly control a culture.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the OP stated examples with at most 5 digits, would this work for all input?

```
var result = (decimal)((double) input).ToString(); //with input e.g. 20.12500M
```

I know that the precision of double and decimal is not the same and this can lead to rounding when performing calculations, but maybe for this given question it is watertight.