# Format decimal with fewest possible digits after decimal separator

Tags: c#

I am storing a variety of different sizes as a decimal in SQL server, such as:

> 10oz, 3.3oz, 100ml, 1.75litres

When I pull this number out as a decimal and do ToString() I end up with too many extra digits such as

> 10.000, 3.300, 100.00, 1.750

What I want is basically this :

```
decimal.Parse("1.7500").ToString().TrimEnd('0', '.')
```

to get me `1.75` or `10`

I cannot seem to figure out the format string for this.

In Visual Studio debugger if I do `decimal.Parse("1.7500")` it will show it to me as `1.75` but when I do `ToString()` it becomes `1.7500`.

[Decimal.Round(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899828/16940) is no good because the format is not fixed.

Comment: If you're targetting .NET 4.0, the answer in this thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right

Comment: thanks @keyboardP - tried searching but just couldn't find the existing answers. this one is good too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you cast to `float` and display with `G` format, it will remove the trailing `0`.

Comment: I'd be very interested to see what Visual Studio is doing to display a decimal rounded as 1.75. (and @ja72 I switched to a decimal because a float was giving me some nasty 0.00000012 type rounding errors)

Comment: @ja72 That will lose precision.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit odd but it does work:

```
var dec = 1.0004000m;
var str = dec.ToString("0;#############################.#############################");
```

It seems best in this case to take advantage of custom formatters.

You can always write an extension method out of the `ToString` so that you don't have to type all the #'s that often. 'Course if you need digit grouping, insert the appropriate grouping separator where needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(decimal.Parse("1.7500").ToString(),"^(0+)|(?<=\.\d+)(0+)$")
```