# Get number of significant digits to the right of decimal point in c# Decimal

Tags: c#, .net

I would like a c# function with this signature:

```
int GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(decimal d)
```

It should behave as follows when called:

```
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2.12300m); // returns 3
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2.123m);   // returns 3
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2.103450m);  // returns 5
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2.0m); // returns 0
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2.00m); // returns 0
    GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(2m); // returns 0
```

i.e. for a given decimal, i want the number of significant decimal places to the right of the decimal point. So trailing zeros can be ignored. 
My fallback is to turn the decimal into a string, trim trailing zeros, and get the length this way. But is there a better way ?

NOTE: I may be using the word "significant" incorrectly here. The required return values in the example should hopefully explain what i'm after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some very good answers here [Parse decimal and filter extra 0 on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right)

```
decimal d = -123.456700m;

decimal n = d / 1.000000000000000000000000000000m;  // -123.4567m

int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(n);

int count = bits[3] >> 16 & 255; // 4        or byte count = (byte)(bits[3] >> 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

I can help you to do the same with a few string operations, This may be a workaround solution for your problem, anyway consider this suggestion, and hope that it would help you

```
static int GetSignificantNumberOfDecimalPlaces(decimal d)
{
    string inputStr = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int decimalIndex = inputStr.IndexOf(".") + 1;
    if (decimalIndex == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return inputStr.Substring(decimalIndex).TrimEnd(new[] { '0' }).Length;    
}
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZScNI) with all the specified inputs

Comment: thanks, it does work, but i was hoping for something that didn't have to resort to converting to strings.

Comment: @MoeSisko: I too hope(trying) for some perfect solution than this workaround.

Comment: @un-lucky: You need to ensure the invarian culture is used when using "." as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered before: [stackoverflow.com/a/13493771/4779385](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture/13493771#13493771)

```
decimal argument = 123.456m;
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(argument)[3])[2];
```

Comment: there's a difference between 123.456m and 123.4560m. i.e. if the decimal i pass in has trailing zeros, the routine should ignore them.
Your code works for calling with 123.456m, but not for 123.4560m, for example.

Answer (score -1):

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NumberofOnes

{

```
public class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Console.WriteLine("enter numbers");

        decimal argument = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        double count = Convert.ToDouble(decimal.Remainder(argument, 1));

        string number = count.ToString();

        int decimalCount = 0;

        if (number.Length > 1)

        {

            decimalCount = number.Length - 2;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("decimal:" + decimalCount);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

}

hope this work!!