# Format a decimal using at least 2 places and at most 6 places

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

To meet a specification I need to format a decimal value with the rule:

- *All values must have at least two decimal places and at most six*.

Example:

```
Value        Formatted
1            1.00
1.1          1.10
1.1234       1.1234
1.123456     1.123456
1.12345678   1.123456
```

I guess I'll end using a condition, but I wonder if there is a format string which can do this.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeroes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried:

`.ToString("0.00####");`

Comment: This is incorrect. 1.12345678 will turn into 1.123457 (note the rounding)