# Set the precision for Decimal numbers in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

Is it possible to change the precision for Decimal numbers in C# globally ?

In TypeScript I am using the framework [Decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/), where I can change the precision of the Decimal operations globally like so `Decimal.set({ precision: 15})`. This means that the operation will return at most 15 decimal digits.

- **TypeScript**:the operation `5/3` returns `1.66666666666667`
- **C#** the operation`5m/3m` returns `1.6666666666666666666666666667`

Is there some similar setting for Decimal values in C# ? How can I accomplish this in C# ?

Comment: No, there is no way to globally set an arbitrary precision of `decimal`.

Comment: Do you want to display it with less digits but calculate with all digits or do you need to round stuff?

Comment: @Zorkind Well it depends on the scale factor...unit could theoretically be market value of Apple in billions of dollars, and someone who has a share quantity of 0.1% might want to know up to the last penny how much its worth. Don't assume information you don't know anything about, chances are you'll be wrong.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I want that the digits don't exceed the precision that I specified. The perfect solution would be something similar as how Decimal.js does it. Otherwise every proposition is welcome.

Comment: decimal.Round(123.123456789m, 6); is designed to round to specific number of places.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're asking, but you could initialize a `NumberFormatInfo` object within the global scope and use it to format decimals. Here is an example:

```
using System.Globalization;

NumberFormatInfo setPrecision = new NumberFormatInfo();    
setPrecision.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;    
decimal test = 1.22223;

Console.Write(test.ToString("N", setPrecision)); //Should write 1.23

setPrecision.NumberDecimalDigits = 3;
test = 5m/3m;

Console.Write(test.ToString("N", setPrecision)); //Should write 1.667
```

MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

NumberDecimalDigits usage example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good find how does one clear the value once u have set it though ?.

Answer (score 20):

There is no generic setting for `decimal` precision. Your best chance is implementing these methods in your extensions.

```
var decimalValue = 5m/3m;
var str = decimalValue.ToString("0.##############");//1.66666666666667
```

or you could use `Round`;

```
var decimalValue = 5m/3m;
decimalValue = decimal.Round(decimalValue, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739340/format-a-decimal-using-at-least-2-places-and-at-most-6-places/6739384

Answer (score 9):

The documentation of `Decimal.js` states the following:

> **precision**
>
> The *maximum* number of significant digits of the result of an
>   operation.
>
> All functions which return a Decimal will round the return value to
>   precision significant digits except Decimal, absoluteValue, ceil,
>   floor, negated, round, toDecimalPlaces, toNearest and truncated.

Well, if you really need that behavior globally, then simply implement a wrapper type that does that, you've got a good specification to go by:

```
public struct RoundedDecimal
{
    public static int Precision { get; private set; }

    public static Decimal AbsoluteValue(
        RoundedDecimal d) => Math.Abs(d.value);

    //same with ceiling, floor, etc.

    private readonly decimal value;

    public RoundedDecimal(decimal d)
    {
        value = Decimal.Round(d, Precision);
    }

    public static void SetPrecision(int precision)
    {
        Precision = precision; /*omitted argument validation*/ }

     public static implicit operator Decimal(
         RoundedDecimal d) => d.value;

    public static explicit operator RoundedDecimal(
        decimal d) => new RoundedDecimal(d);

    public static RoundedDecimal operator +(
        RoundedDecimal left, RoundedDecimal right) =>
           new RoundedDecimal(left.value + right.value);

    //etc.
}
```

Performance wise this will not be very impressive but if its the behavior *you need* then, by all means, implement it!

DISCLAIMER: written code on my cell phone, so its bound to have bugs... simpy trying to get the idea across.

Comment: You must have a pretty big phone.. or micro usb keyboard... this formatting is better than some I've seen written on computers. Well done.