# Format decimal in C# with at least 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal, rounding

Is there a display formatter that will output decimals as these string representations in C# without doing any rounding?

The decimal may have 2 decimal places, but if it has more precision it should be included in the resultant string and not rounded off.

Examples:

```
decimal  -> string
20       -> 20,00
20.00    -> 20,00
20.5     -> 20,50
20.5000  -> 20,50
20.125   -> 20,125
20.12500 -> 20,125
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: similar but not identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeros-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you have a reasonable upper limit for the maximum number of digits:

```
 ToString("0.00#######")
```

will handle all your examples but **not** `1.23456789012345M`

Comment: If you have no upper limit: `ToString("0.00##########################")`. Decimal type supports at most 28 decimal digits.