# Show SQL decimal type without decimal if there are no decimals

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, decimal, format-string

I am using ASP.NET Core v2,

See picture showing SQL data type and the code in the model

I do not want to display decimal if there are no decimals

The following html is used to show the input on web page

```
<input tabindex=@ordTab asp-for="@Model.OrderLineList[i].NoInvoAb" />
```

below is SQL

[image]

below is the model

I have tried many different display formats/dataformatstring but it does not seem to matter what I use, like the formatting does not seem to apply at all

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
[Display(Name = "Ordered")]
public decimal NoInvoAb { get; set; }
```

This is my result which is wrong, if the value is 2, it should display 2 and not 2,00

[image]

what am I doing wrong

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104615/best-way-to-display-decimal-without-trailing-zeroes

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayFormat` by default is for *display*. Here, it looks like the value is in an input. If you want the format apply there *as well*, then you need to add `ApplyFormatInEditMore = true` to your `DisplayFormat` attribute.

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Ordered")]
public decimal NoInvoAb { get; set; }
```