# Percent C# with decimal places (ex 30.2% or .05%)

Tags: c#, string, decimal, percentage

I've tried to make my tool display  a field into % by doing some math then converting it.

Here is my code and what I would like to do is these things.

If the result is a value that comes out to a flat % then display the flat % example result of calculation comes out to 3% then show 3% otherwise if it's a decimal show 3.1% and one for if the value becomes less than 1% so .5 or .05 for example.

A little background for the code. the value tbOptionlvl5 will have a value out of 10,000 . 10,000 being 100% so the example might be lets say 510.

```
    if (Item_Is_Rare() && int.Parse(TbOptionID5.Text) >= 0)
    {
        lblProb5.Text = "";
        decimal result = ((int.Parse(TbOptionLvl5.Text) * 100) / 10000);
        lblProb5.Text = Convert.ToString(result) + "%";
    }
```

here is my code for calling the function

```
if (TbOptionID10.Text == "-1")
        lblProb10.Text = "";
        if (TbOptionID10.Text != "-1" && TbOptionID10.Text != "")
        {
            if (int.Parse(TbOptionID10.Text) > 10000)
                TbOptionID10.Text = Convert.ToString(10000);
            Update_Probability_Text();
        }
```

Comment: "if the value becomes less than 1% so .5 or .05" - can you be a bit more clear on your expectations? Maybe just give a few explicit examples

Comment: So far it sounds like you just want to display decimals without trailing zeros: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3104615/5803406

Comment: example i want the value to display simply the % so example would be if tbOptionLvl5.text has a value of 30 you would do 30*100  = 3,000 /10,000 would give you .3%   my original code wont display .3% it would instead not display any % so 0%

Comment: here is a video of it in action notice the % isn't displaying correctly.
https://gyazo.com/3f515f2fddba4571975a9b51d23e2562

Comment: From the linked question: "You're doing integer division, from the sounds of it."

Comment: it appears to be solved when i change the number /10000 to /1000m 
thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(result.ToString("##.##"));
            builder.Append(" %");
            lblProb5.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

use a decimal specifier during the math.

```
decimal result = (tbText.text * 100) /10000
```

Fixed is as follows

```
 decimal result = (tbText.text * 100) /10000m
```

Comment: Right, `tbText.text * 100`. What is this, Visual Basic with `Option Strict Off`?